# What's the best practice to implement md-toast in a web app?

Tags: angularjs, toast, angular-material

I'm new to AngularJS and Material. 
What's the best practice to implement dynamic Angular Material toast across the entire site? The demo [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast) tells me that I need to include the code in controllers. However, I don't want to have duplicated md-toast code in all my controllers. What's the right thing to do here? Thanks!

Comment: You might want to add a code-snippit instead of the demo link. The link may break if angular modifies their site and your question won't help someone else out in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a service and inject that service in each controller.

```
angular.module('toast', ['ngMaterial'])
.service('toastService', function($scope, $mdToast, $document)){
    [...]
}
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, toastService) {
    toastService.showToast(message,params,...);
}
```

In service you write toast logic in the same way you would in the controller, but instead a string for message, you use variables. Then you can call the function in service passing the message declared in the controller, and other params you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking your time. How do you access toastService.showToast() in the html/view when using controllerAs syntax? Also, I think you can't inject $scope into a service unfortunately.

Comment: yes! In controllerAs syntax replace $scope with this, so you can do that:
`this.showToast = toastService.showToast`

And in HTML can write something like that:
` <button ng-click="showToast(message)">Click me!</button>`